# Statement ignored in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create procedure that return table. for that I have created Object and procedure as below. but it gives me compile time error,

```
CREATE TYPE INTERN_OBJECT AS OBJECT
( companyTitle VARCHAR2(100),
  schoolName VARCHAR2(30),
  RANK NUMBER(3),
  NUM_INTERNS NUMBER(3));

CREATE TYPE INTERN_TAB AS TABLE OF INTERN_OBJECT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INTERN_DATA_Function RETURN INTERN_TAB
IS
  r_INTERN_TAB INTERN_TAB;
  r_index number := 0;
BEGIN
  r_INTERN_TAB := INTERN_OBJECT();
  FOR r IN (select company.title AS title ,school.name AS name ,RANK AS RANK ,count(SID) AS NO_OF_INTERN from school join student on school.SCHID = student.SCHOOLID JOIN INTERN on student.SID = INTERN.SID JOIN COMPANY ON INTERN.CMPID = COMPANY.CMPID GROUP BY company.title,school.name,RANK ORDER BY count(SID) DESC)
  LOOP
          r_INTERN_TAB.extend;
      r_index := r_index + 1;  
      r_INTERN_TAB(r_index):= INTERN_TAB(r.title, r.name ,r.RANK , r.NO_OF_INTERN);
    END LOOP;
  return r_INTERN_TAB;
END;
```

when I hit run I got below error:

```
ERROR at line 11: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
1. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INTERN_DATA_Function RETURN INTERN_TAB
2. IS
3.   r_INTERN_TAB INTERN_TAB;
```

I don't know where is the probelm. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `/` after each statement, especially if you're running the above script in SQL*Plus:

```
CREATE TYPE INTERN_OBJECT AS OBJECT
( companyTitle VARCHAR2(100),
  schoolName VARCHAR2(30),
  RANK NUMBER(3),
  NUM_INTERNS NUMBER(3));
/

CREATE TYPE INTERN_TAB AS TABLE OF INTERN_OBJECT;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INTERN_DATA_Function RETURN INTERN_TAB
IS
  r_INTERN_TAB INTERN_TAB;
  r_index number := 0;
BEGIN
  r_INTERN_TAB := INTERN_OBJECT();
  FOR r IN (select company.title AS title ,school.name AS name ,RANK AS RANK ,count(SID) AS NO_OF_INTERN from school join student on school.SCHID = student.SCHOOLID JOIN INTERN on student.SID = INTERN.SID JOIN COMPANY ON INTERN.CMPID = COMPANY.CMPID GROUP BY company.title,school.name,RANK ORDER BY count(SID) DESC)
  LOOP
          r_INTERN_TAB.extend;
      r_index := r_index + 1;  
      r_INTERN_TAB(r_index):= INTERN_TAB(r.title, r.name ,r.RANK , r.NO_OF_INTERN);
    END LOOP;
  return r_INTERN_TAB;
END;
/
```

Comment: I am running this through SQL command from chrom browser.after addming / i get the same error. no any change

Comment: is this correct way to run or do I need to download another s/w for this?

Comment: You would need to consult the documentation for whichever plugin it is that you're using.

Comment: what was the issue in the end?

Comment: sorry for late reply. issue is with  r_INTERN_TAB := INTERN_OBJECT(); code. here It should be r_INTERN_TAB := INTERN_TAB ();